# journalctl only goes back 1 hour

Tags: linux, systemd

The linux journalctl seems to only store 1 hour of history -- I would like to keep 24 hours of history, how do i do that?

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2022-12-15 18:48:30 GMT, end at Thu 2022-12-15 19:55:13 GMT. --
Dec 15 18:48:30 a23 jokerd[638301]: 2022-12-15T18:48:30.182Z        INFO        root        we have not yet seen this joke - temporarily>
```

We missed a very important thing.

How do I simply and immediately force 24 hours of logs forever?

(as linux gets more complex with systemd it seems like simple things -- keeping my logs, is suddenly an expert question)

Comment: Journalctl deals with storage in terms of megabytes. It has no concept of days. `man journald.conf` The log could have been lost due to rotation or outage.